# Homebrew vim and Numpy don't support options anymore?

Tags: python, numpy, vim, homebrew

I have my Numpy installed through `brew install numpy --with-python3`, and it worked well. But right now, I was trying to upgrade it with `brew upgrade numpy`, then it forces me to install `python@2`.

When I do `brew info numpy`, I get the `python@2` is now required now. Is there something wrong with this? Why would `python@2` become required option, and no other options at all now.

```
> brew info numpy
numpy: stable 1.15.4 (bottled), HEAD
Package for scientific computing with Python
https://www.numpy.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.15.4_1 (738 files, 16.4MB) *
Built from source on 2018-12-14 at 20:22:36 with: --without-python@2
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/numpy.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: gcc ✔
Required: openblas ✔, python ✔, python@2 ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
If you use system python (that comes - depending on the OS X version -
with older versions of numpy, scipy and matplotlib), you may need to
ensure that the brewed packages come earlier in Python's sys.path with:
  mkdir -p     /Users/cheng/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import sys; sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/cheng/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
==> Analytics
install: 30,333 (30 days), 105,414 (90 days), 395,859 (365 days)
install_on_request: 5,810 (30 days), 19,970 (90 days), 74,025 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

I did the same check for `vim`, I'm pretty sure I installed with `brew install vim --with-python`, then it did not install `Lua` for me. But now, `Lua` is a required one too, and all the options are gone. Any idea what happened to my brew?

```
vim: stable 8.1.0650 (bottled), HEAD
Vi 'workalike' with many additional features
https://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with:
  ex-vi (because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view)
  macvim (because vim and macvim both install vi* binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.0500 (1,442 files, 23.6MB) *
  Built from source on 2018-10-29 at 21:18:34 with: --with-override-system-vi
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔, lua ✘, perl ✔, python ✔, ruby ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 63,426 (30 days), 178,055 (90 days), 833,882 (365 days)
install_on_request: 56,810 (30 days), 159,741 (90 days), 701,651 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the basis behind the decision to remove all options from `homebrew-core` formulas here: [Remove all options from Homebrew/homebrew-core formulae #31510](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510).

Users now need to maintain formulas in personal taps (https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap) so search for an old working formula and use that.